# PHP upload requests not concurrent

Tags: php, apache, blueimp

I'm using the [Blueimp jQuery File Uploader](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload) to handle multiple file uploads.

It works fine with one exception: It doesn't upload files concurrently but waits for one request to finish to start the other. It seems to be on the side of Apache/PHP because the requests are initiated at the same time and waiting for each other to finish.

Here's my waterfall:
[image]

My `uploadImage` function only has `sleep(1); die();` for this test.

Shouldn't it make 5 requests simultaneously for a total of 1 second instead of 5 seconds sequentially? I wouldn't know how to do this even if i wanted to. Is this php setting or Apache?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My gut feeling is you probably use sessions in your upload script, and they all fight to get the session lock. Well, actually they don't fight, they just wait for the lock to be release before doing anything.

There's a detailed description of the issue here:
http://konrness.com/php5/how-to-prevent-blocking-php-requests/

See if you can avoid sessions, or close them as soon as possible (aka, get what you need from the session, close it, and then `sleep(1)`.

Comment: You go it. That was it. As soon as I added  `session_write_close();` it worked. Thanks!